# Dúvida ao salvar imagem no banco mysql

Tags: java

Boa noite, é o seguinte:
Tenho um JLabel = jlImagem, onde é carregado uma imagem como mostra o método btnCaminhoImagemActionPerformed.

Porém quero usar o botão salvar para inserir a imagem no banco de dados, mas não sei como fazer para pegar o valor desse jLabel qual parâmetro eu deveria passar no PreparedStatement?
OBS: A imagem está como longBlob na minha base.
Desde já agradeço a colaboração.

```
 private void btnCaminhoImagemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
             JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
             fc.showOpenDialog(this);
             File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
             String path = f.getAbsolutePath();


             ImageIcon imagem = new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());

             Image imag = imagem.getImage().getScaledInstance(jlImagem.getWidth(), jlImagem.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

             jlImagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imag));

  }     




private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

   conexaoProdutos.conexao();

 PreparedStatement pst = conexaoProdutos.conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO produto (imagem) VALUES (?)");

        pst.set(1, );//O que usar como parâmetro?
        pst.execute();

    }
```

Comment: Tente o seguinte:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19310279/5524514

Comment: Blz... Obrigado...